# Replicate From OpenDJ to OpenLDAP?

Tags: openldap, opends

I am considering retiring some of our older OpenDJ LDAP servers and replacing with OpenLDAP. (seems to be more widely supported)

I am wondering if it's possible to replicate directly from OpenDJ to OpenLDAP as an interim solution to remove the OpenDJ slaves and then flip the master over later.

Is LDAP replication implementation specific or more general?

I guess I'll have to just go give it a try, but I was looking for advice from someone who's been down this road.

Answer (score 0):

There is no standard for LDAP replication, and thus it's implementation specific.
I would encourage you to upgrade your older OpenDJ server with most recent version, replication is working across versions, and thus the upgrade is smooth and without any service downtime.
Regards,
Ludovic
Product Manager for OpenDJ at ForgeRock.

Comment: I'm confused.  Why would I upgrade OpenDJ when I want to migrate to OpenLDAP?  It seems I'll be dumping and importing LDIFs.  Any gotchas here?

Comment: I'm suggesting that you might be better at upgrading your OpenDJ server than migrating to OpenLDAP. Just saying...

Answer (score 0):

Ludovic is correct: as far as I know replication is product-specific.

To solve your issue, I would advocate a third party solution as [lsc](http://lsc-project.org), which can take cron-directed snapshots from any directory to any other.

While I didn't try OpenDJ as a source provider per lsc, I'm quite optimistic it could be done.